# How to create a clean master branch from the origin project of a fork?

Tags: git

Alright, so I accidentally pushed commits to the master branch of my fork, and submitted the branch for a PR.

I need to create another PR now, but I don't know anyway I can create a new branch based off a unmodified master branch (because I accidentally pushed commits there). How can I create a branch based off the master branch of the forks origin project?

To clarify: I don't have a clean copy of the master branch to create another branch based off it. What are some soultions I can use to fix this?

Comment: Do a reset and force push. Or revert your commit.

Comment: If I revert, the PR from the master branch would get messed up

Comment: you probably shouldn't be making a PR off the master branch anyway. Just delete the PR and make a new one off a different branch

Comment: You could checkout a particular HASH (`git checkout <hash>`) and then create a branch from that point (`git branch <branchname>`). Now you have created a branch at whatever commit was your "clean start point". Finally you need to checkout this new branch (`git checkout <branchname>`). It won't revert or delete anything you did (including mistakes) but it will give you a new branch at the correct start point (That is if I understand you question correctly).

Comment: Hangon - do you mean you commited changes to the local master branch, but you have not pushed them remotely yet? - in that case you just need to do: `git checkout -b <some-new-branch-name> origin/master`. This will create you a new local branch at the same commit as origin/master (different to your local master). And then as Joe says, just delete your old branch (or not - doesn't matter so much since its only a local branch)

Answer (score 1):

You can go to a previous commit and branch from there. Go to your master branch and use `git log` to see your commit history and copy the hash of the commit you want to go back to (one before your latest, it looks like).

Use `git checkout <hash>` to get on that commit. Then `git branch <new branch name>` to create a new branch based off the clean master branch.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new branch off a previous commit with

```
git checkout -b <new_branch_name> <commit hash>
```

However, it seems that the bigger problem is that you now have commits that are in master that shouldn't be there.  Short of a force push to remove them, the only other option you have is to revert those commits.  You mention that you are on your own fork, which may make force pushing a better option if no one else is also working on your fork.  If you want to do that to fix your master, you can do

```
git reset --hard <commit hash to revert to>
```